# Conditional formatting Excel 2010

Tags: excel

I have a list of dates in a column starting with c8 thru C100.  I applied the following conditional format and it will no work: =TODAY()-C8>30.  I tried both the second and the last rule changing the color to red.  Using the last rule all cells turn red except dates that = false such as dates less than 30 days..  I would not want to change the color of blank cells. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear what you are trying to do, using that formula on its own will turn the dates red if they are more than 30 days in the past, is that what you want? If you have other rules applied first they will take precedence.

If you don't want to format blank cells change to this:

`=AND(C8<>"",TODAY()-C8>30)`

Comment: I enter a date, e.g., today.  after 30 days has elapsed I want the cell to turn red,

Comment: Yes, that's what that formula does .....as long as you aren't already formatting that date with some other condition - does it work?

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
=AND( NOT(ISBLANK(C8)), TODAY()-C8 > 30)
```